# Audio not detected with Transparent Video Formats (Quicktime - PNG/QtAnimation- AAC/PCM)

Tags: audio, file-formats, alpha

On importing a transparent .mov file (Quicktime - PNG/QtAnimation- AAC/PCM) , the audio is not detected by the Videoeditors (Powerdirector17 < Davinci Resolve doesn't support the above format> ).

Eventhough Powerdirector supports these formats, the audio doesn't play (https://help.cyberlink.com/stat/help/powerdirector/18/enu/05_01_01_support_file_formats.htm).

Which Transparency supported Video formats + Audio formats combinations are commonly supported in Videoeditors ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know PowerDirector, but I would try exporting as ProRes 4444 with alpha (sometimes called 'Millions of colors+'.
This works with Adobe Premiere, Final Cut, Resolve and other editors fine.